# How to open or convert old .efx (eFax) documents without PowerPC support?

Tags: pdf, file-conversion

I have a number of very old `.efx` documents (from 2004) that were sent to me from the eFax service.  They are no longer available on eFax's website (so I can't just get them from there and change the format). (I changed eFax's setting a long time ago to send me new faxes in PDF format, so this problem only applies to my very old faxes.)

The most recent version of eFax Messenger is a PowerPC app so it can't be opened on recent versions of Mac OS X.

The simplest way seems to be just downloading eFax Messenger on a computer with Windows, but since I don't have access to one that's not an option.

So does anyone know of an all-Mac way to open these files?  Or a way to convert them into a file format that I can open, e.g., PDF or TIFF?

Comment: relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/202465/is-there-a-fix-for-mac-os-to-convert-efx-files-to-pdf-or-word-with-emessenger

Answer (score 2):

Since you updated your settings to receive faxes now in PDF, you can:

- Fax the EFX documents to your assigned eFax® number (via website or
  e-mail).
- The new files should be received as PDF.

If you need further assistance, please let us know and we can convert them to PDF for you.  You can respond to this thread or contact us on Twitter [@efaxcares](https://twitter.com/efaxcares) so we can exchange contact info.